# isolating user run scripts on docker without performance impact

Tags: design-patterns, security, architectural-patterns, multitenancy, kubernetes

Scenario:
We have a application (web based), in a small part of this application a users is able to create a small python script to mutate (in memory) data. Currently all of these scripts (if it is directly run from the frontend) are run on the same docker instance. We want to separate this so there is 0 chance of different users accessing each others data. If the scripts are executed by a scheduler (because they can be scheduled) then they are run in their own separate container.

The challenge we are facing is cost vs performance. it would be easy to spin up a container per user and have everything executed separately. However many users won't use the script function so that would be very wasteful.

But if we spin up a container only when a users runs a script then the performance would be too low because it takes (i don't know the exact number) 30 seconds for a container to be spinned up.

I think the best solution is to provision a few containers (depending on the amount of people that are online/working on functionality that allow for scripts) and whenever a script is run spin up a new container and kill the old one after completion.
Kind of like a load balancer.

I'm looking for some architecture principals/design patterns/etc. that tackle this use case.

Comment: There's no need to overthink this. Resources that are irregularly required by different workers and are expensive enough to be reused should be kept in a *Pool*. Pools are not for database connections only just because that's their most common use.

Comment: The overhead of running a container (vs running a program outside of the container) is well less than 1s with Docker, and typically faster with other container implementations. Assuming no image has to be pulled. Are you sure you can't just start the container on demand? But if your system needs to do some expensive initialization between container launch and running the user script, then sure, a resource pool could help reduce latency.

Comment: There is no real out of the box pod/container pooling or a 'single use' container in k8s is there?

Comment: @amon yeh the problem is that the entire code inside the pod has like a 10 second startup time with loading data from a database and connecting to different services. Yes there is definitely something wrong there but no way to get the entire start of the pod + code within a second that we know of. So therefore pooling seemed to be the best option.